# jquery tipsy. trigger:focus not working on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [this plugin for displaying tooltips](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)

Looking at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CmmUC/1/

You'll see that the tootip does not appear. It works if you change the javascript to

```
$('.tooltip').tipsy({ gravity: 'w' });
```

​Why does plugin hate 'focus'? Am I missing something obvious that's causing the issue?

I'm working in the latest stable Chrome.

Comment: The tooltip appears when you give focus to the element (click a radio button) If you remove the trigger then you can just hover and it will display. Seems to be functioning correctly

Comment: Works fine for me in FF12, just tried it in Chrome and it doesn't work ;|

Comment: @deifwud. It works in IE but not in chrome. **Irony++**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my updated version of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CmmUC/7/

basically you need to add the option `trgger: 'manual'` upon instantiation and maually show/hide the tipsy using the jquery hover function.